# get room of a socket in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

How do I retrieve the rooms a socket is a member of?
I'm using socket.io version 1.4

I tried with `this.socket.adapter.rooms` but I received this error in the chrome console: `Cannot read property 'rooms' of undefined`

In my client code I have this method:

```
send(msg) {
        if(msg != ''){
            var clientInfo = [];
            clientInfo.push(msg);
            clientInfo.push(socket.id);
            clientInfo.push(this.socket.adapter.rooms);
            socket.emit('message', clientInfo);
        }
    }
```

On my server side:

```
socket.on('message', function(clientInfo){
        var clientmessage = clientInfo[0];
        var clientid = clientInfo[1];
        var clientroom = clientInfo[2];
        io.to(clientroom).emit('messageSent', clientmessage);
    });
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.   `socket.id` is a unique string for each socket and also corresponds to a room name that only that socket is in.  There's also a list of rooms that a given socket is a member of, but I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for?

Comment: "There's also a list of rooms that a given socket is a member of"... I'm searching for this.

Comment: Then, please edit your question to say that's what you're looking for.  And, based on your description of the error you are seeing, we need to see a lot more context for your code to understand what `this.socket` is.  Also, there is no "single" room name that a socket might belong to as your question implies.  A socket can be in many rooms.

Comment: And, is this code client side code or server side code?

Comment: The client-side socket does not know what rooms it is in.  That is only server-side info.

Comment: Server-side, a socket has a list of rooms in `socket.rooms`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Server side, you can get a list of rooms a socket is in with:

```
socket.rooms
```

Client side, a socket does not know what rooms it is in.  The whole concept of rooms is a server-side concept and all the data structures are maintained there.  If a client wanted to know what rooms it was in, it would either have to keep track of what rooms it requested to be a member of or it would have to ask the server what rooms it is in.

There is one oddity about the server-side `socket.rooms` structure.  It is apparently not updated real-time.  If you do `socket.join("someRoom")` and then immediately look at `socket.rooms`, you will not see the `someRoom` name listed.    But, if you look on `process.nextTick()` or on `setTimeout()`, you will see it in `socket.rooms`.  I haven't delved into the socket.io source code to figure out why that is the way it is, but apparently something is only being updated asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

```
            Object.keys(socket.rooms).forEach(function(room, idx) {
                if(idx!=0){
                    console.log(idx,"-->",room)
                }
             });
```

By the above code you can identify all the rooms the socket have joined.
You can skip the first room which is in index 0 as it is the default room a socket will connect on connection.

Tested this with SocketIO 1.7 and works well.